# JavaScript find names in strings

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, search

What's a good JavaScript library for searching a given string for a large list of names.

For example, given a list of 1000 politicians names find every instance in a string and wrap it in a `span`.

Priorities are performance with a growing list of names, and accuracy in determining difference between eg, "Tony Blair", "Tony Blair III".

For example, this:

```
["Tony Blair", "Margaret Thatcher", "Tony Blairite", "Tony Blair III", etc...]
"The best PM after Tony Blair was Margaret Thatcher."
```

Becomes:

```
"The best PM after <span class="mp">Tony Blair</span> was <span class="mp">Margaret Thatcher</span>."
```

Comment: This could be trivial with a loop and `indexOf` but I'd be curious to find more efficient solutions, maybe starting with sorting the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ['foo','bar'];
var content = "this foo is bar foobar  foo ";
for (var c=0,l=names.length;c<l;c++) {
  var r = new RegExp("\\b("+names[c]+")\\b","gi");
  content = content.replace(r,'<span class="mp">$1</span>');
}
```