# Search a text from a list containing texts separated by ","

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following which contains a list of names

```
 var myList = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Names));
```

I have a textbox in which the user enters a name and I have to search through myList and see if it contains that name?

How can I do that?  I can see the data in myList are as follows:

> Albert, Jack, Jim, Tom

Read textbox value :

```
var NameEntered = $("#Name").val();
```

e.g, If the user enters the name "Albert", it should be able to give me a true as answer in javasript or razor

Comment: Is that coffeescript?

Comment: @Bergi it's probably C# (razor). But definitely not plain js.

Comment: No, C doesn't use `@` like that

Comment: Can you show us that textbox, and how you get its content?

Comment: @Barmar in Razor, the `@` indicates that some C# is about to be used

Comment: possible duplicate of [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming modern browser:

```
if(NameEntered && myList.indexOf(NameEntered) >= 0){
    alert("This name is in the list: " + NameEntered );
}
```

However, this is very primitive. A better solution would be to split the string into array and check each member for the existance of name.

Check this out: [JavaScript find names in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430525/javascript-find-names-in-strings)

Comment: @Bergi what browser are you using? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No but `if(["Albert",…].indexOf("Albert")){ alert(…); }` does not alert (and any browser that does is buggy)

Comment: Sorry my bad, fixed. But anyway this is a very simple solution because it does not account for capitalization and will work with strings like "bert" or "im" :)